# How does app engine flexible environment works?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

How does app engine flexible environment works? It creates one BIG instance, by increase memory and CPU capacity, or creates several small instances?

How I can implement one BIG instance, which will increase memory and CPU only, without creating new instances?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the resource settings to increase your host size. 
 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings